# Subsonic 3 .Save() VS .Update() and .Add()

Tags: subsonic

What is the difference between:
.Save();
.Add();
.Update():

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't mention which templates you're using (I'm going to assume ActiveRecord), but as a general rule:

- Save will insert if the object
  `IsNew==true` or otherwise it will
  update.
- Add will always insert a new record.
- Update will only update an object
  with `IsNew==false` and will fail if
  there is no corresponding record in
  the db for the instance.

Comment: Thanks John. Yes, I am using Active Records.
BTW, I read a bit of your "How I Use SubSonic" article but noticed it 's for Subsonic 2. Now, this is my first time using Subonic (v 3) and looking for some advise on how to layer my application (DAL, BLL, UI). I for sure don't want to expose the DAL to my UI. Any tips?

Comment: Don't use ActiveRecord ;) I would start by familiarizing yourself with the LinqTemplates. It makes it a lot easier to separate your layers. That's a good idea for another blog post though...bringing the 2.x stuff up to speed on 3.

Comment: Thanks John.I will read about LinqTempaltes. 
I think it is time for a new blog post.

Comment: What's the difference between ActiveRecord and LinqTemplates?

Comment: The LinqTemplates use the Repository pattern which makes it easier to keep all your data access code in one place (far from the UI)

Comment: John,
any example of how LinqTempaltes would make things easier?